# How to find the base character in OpenType GPOS lookup format 4.1?

Tags: fonts, opentype

The [OpenType documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/gpos#lookup-type-4-mark-to-base-attachment-positioning-subtable) states that for GPOS lookups of type 4.1 (Mark-to-Base Attachment Positioning), the application must do the following:

> To identify the base glyph that combines with a mark, the
> text-processing client must look backward in the glyph string from the
> mark to the preceding base glyph.

But how far do I need to look back?  Is this always the preceding character?  Or do I need to skip over all glyphs in the marks coverage table?  Or go back until I find a glyph in the base coverage table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MarkBasePosFormat1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/gpos#mark-to-base-attachment-positioning-format-1-mark-to-base-attachment-point) table has a base coverage subtable that specifies a set of glyphs to match on. When determining if a given lookup will apply, you want to match a glyph sequence that begins with one of the glyphs specified in the base coverage subtable.

Going the other direction, from a mark backwards, you skip over any glyphs that are identified in the [Glyph Class Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/gdef#glyph-class-definition-table) subtable of the GDEF table as mark glyphs. When you get to a candidate glyph, you need to check that it's included in the base coverage table.

I see the [Harfbuzz implementation](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/blob/master/src/hb-ot-layout-gpos-table.hh) has a few other details it checks as it scans backwards, you might want to check that: look for the apply method in the MarkBasePosFormat1 struct. (I'm not suggesting that Harfbuzz is the reference implementation that defines the intent of the spec; but it is widely used and is available as open source.)